# How to use botframework's sendTyping() while bot recognizer makes async requst to Luis Model?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

`session.sendTyping()` works perfectly fine, but could figure out how to use it after receiving a message and before sending a message. (while bot's recognizer uses `LuisRecognizer`).

Initially, I thought of Emitting an event, but could not figure out where to place the emitter code.

```
on('sendTyping', (session) => { session.sendTyping() });
emitter.emit('sendTyping', session);
```

Comment: I have tried adding middleware `bot.use({botbuilder: (session, next) =>{})` it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put `session.sendTyping()` at the *beginning of the function* and it will show that until your actual answer is fetched.

I tested this by putting it in the beginning and *delaying send method*.

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: (session, next) => {
    session.sendTyping();   
    next();
  }
});


const foo = (session, args, next) => {  
  // some processing here
  session.send(message);
}
```